# creating outer array php

Tags: php, html, ajax

UPDATE: a solution has been found stated below: however new issue poses i didnt want to keep creating question so updated this one when i use ajax to pass through to html i get the following error response.forEach is not a function

where the code is as below is this because there are now 2 arrays?

```
$.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);
            $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
        });
    });
```

Im Pretty naff when it comes to this type of thing but i need to try get these 2 queries added to 1 ajax I have been told i should add both queries to an outer array but im not sure how to do this and the example i got was $array = $other_array

but im not sure how to write it any help would be greatly appreaciated

```
$sql = "SELECT beacon,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(max(`time`),min(`time`)), '%i.%s') 
AS `delivery_avg` 
FROM `test`.`test` 
where date = CURDATE()
and time > now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
group by beacon ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql2 = 'SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT
beacon,location,date,
COUNT(location) AS counter 
FROM `test`.`test`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() and `time` > NOW() - interval 40 second
GROUP BY beacon) AS SubQueryTable
ORDER BY SubQueryTable.counter DESC;';
$result = $conn->query($sql2);


$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql2);
$rows2 = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
$rows2[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows2);
```

Comment: `i didnt want to keep creating question so updated this one`. Please just one question per post. If you have another question, use the [Ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got most of it right. To get the data in one go, you can combine the arrays (see the line staring with `$result`) and then send it JSON formatted.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT ...";
// Query the database
$result1 = $conn->query($sql);
// Fetch the result
$rows1 = $result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Same for second query
$sql2 = 'SELECT ...';
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$rows2 = $result2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$result = array(
    'query1' => $rows1,
    'query2' => $rows2
);

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Some more hints:

- You only need to run the query once (you have `->query()` and `mysqli_query()` in your code).
- You don't need the loop to get all result rows. The function [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) does that for you.

Comment: I have edited my code to the above but now it doesn't seem to return any results? the page just stays blank

Comment: Please have a look at your error logs, is there anything in there?

Comment: it doesnt return any errors thats the thing if i set it as the above it returns both queries as seperate arrays if i write it by your example it returns nothing

Comment: Got the wrong variables in the combining process. The data variables are `$row1` and `$row2`. Edited the answer.

Comment: sorry i think it may have been my end after some tweaking it was an sql issue where i needed to add full group by

Comment: is there a way that i could add the results of query2 into query 1 array?

Answer (score 0):

When you have your 2 arrays with db results, you can do something like this :

```
$return = array (
    $result,
    $result2
);
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: So i have added this to the end and removed the original echo json()

and it returns false. have i added it the the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sendResponse = array (
    'sql1' => $sqlResult1,
    'sql2' => $sqlResult2
);
echo json_encode($sendResponse);
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

This would be a more suitable and convenient (from JavaScript size) way

```
$response = [];
$response['result_first_query'] = $rows;
$response['result_second_query'] = $rows2;
echo json_encode($response);
```